# Haxe: Calling a function from and outside Class within Main Class

Tags: game-engine, haxe

I would like to call a function that is located outside the `Main` class of my Haxe game.

I am able to add bubbles to the game using: `addChild(new Bubble(player.x, player.y));`

I would like to update the game without using an `EventListener` in each added object.

The follow code: `Bubble.tick();`

Yields this error when run from main:

> Bubble has no field tick

Bubble Class:

```
package;

import flash.Lib;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import openfl.Assets;
import flash.events.Event;

class Bubble extends Sprite
{
    private var newBubble:Bitmap;
    private static var gameBubble:Array<Sprite> = new Array<Sprite>();
    public function new (xpos:Float,ypos:Float) {
        super ();
        this.x = xpos;
        this.y = ypos;
        newBubble = new Bitmap (Assets.getBitmapData ("img/sprite_bubble_16x16.png"));
        newBubble.x = -12.5;
        newBubble.y = -12.5;
        addChild(newBubble);
        gameBubble.push(this);
        trace("Bubble");
    }

    private function tick2(e:Event) {
        this.y -= 5;
        checkPop();
    }

    public function tick() {
        this.y -= 5;
        checkPop();
    }

    private function checkPop() { 
        if(this.y < 0) {
            this.parent.removeChild(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tick` is a member method, not a static method.

```
Bubble.tick()
```

will look for `static public function tick()`, while

```
var b = new Bubble();
b.tick();
```

will look for `public function tick()`.

Static functions are tied to the class, not a specific instance of the object.  Member functions are tied to a specific instance of an object, and can use `this` to access that instance.

Hope that helps

---

EDIT (in response to your comment):

It's hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do, but it looks like you want each "Bubble" to slowly move towards the bottom of the screen, and to be removed when it does.

You have 2 options:

1) Every bubble instance creates it's own timer, and `tick` is a member function (`public function tick`) which does `this.y -= 5` etc.

2) `tick` is a static function (`static public function tick`) which does a loop over every bubble (`for (bubble in gameBubble) { bubble.y-=5; ...etc... }`)

The basic rule: anything static can't access `this`, because it doesn't know which bubble you are talking about, so you'll have to use your static array to go through each of them.

Comment: Interesting so maybe inside bubble i dont need the array but i can start a new array to handle tick?

Comment: Just updated my answer trying to give more info based on what it looks like you're trying to do, showing what the `static` version might look like, and what the `member` version of tick might look like.